# loading="lazy" but for html5 videos

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video

I'm making a scroll-able gallery with flask that shows many`<video>` elements, the video files are small but it still generates a lot of http 206 requests, which are bottle-necking flask.

`<img>` has `loading="lazy"`, which is very convenient.

Is there some way, javascript only or css, to implement such behavior but for `<video>`?

I may use `preload="none"`, but it won't display the first video frame.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you may use a part of this solution :

```html
<video preload="none" src="video.mp4" 
       autoplay="false" poster="poster.jpg"
       muted="false" loop="false">
</video>
```

If preload is `none`, the web browser don't preload the media, but i advice to replace an image with poster attribute.

Preload explanation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_preload.asp)

autoplay explanation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_autoplay.asp)

loop explanation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_loop.asp)

poster explanation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_poster.asp)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried to update the text but it was not possible

Comment: This solution works well when combined with the intersection observer like it is done here: https://imagekit.io/blog/lazy-loading-html-videos/